# Stop screen to blink on setInterval function on Gmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using setInterval function that calls initalize method which fires ajax to get data on google maps(almost 3 ajax for different sort of data on same map, eg:for customers and drivers).
Each time it executes, the screen blinks seems like its loading the map each time.
How can blinking be removed ? flickering of just data on screen is needed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The  effect you are experiencing with setInterval() is normally caused when the function is invoked before  it's completion of  previous call,and setInterval()  repeatedly calls a function or the code snippet you are running and it runs  with a fixed time delay between each and  every call 
Use setTimeout(): which is self invoking.
Also check if its not working on every browser.

Comment: But i need to call my function at regular intervals so is the reason of mine using setInterval

Comment: are you using .load() function after setinterval().

Comment: No, i am calling an ajax function on setInterval  that calls initialize method

Comment: i can just guess  about  what you are doing wrong..it will be better understood if you post the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by just instantiating the map once and updating the rest markers and routes.